# AlpineJs x-for passing js data to Laravel Component as props

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-9, alpine.js

I have select dropdown html element with two options: Enable (with value = 1) and Disable (with value = 0)

These options are provided by items props.

```
// component/select-input.blade.php

@props(['items' => [], 'selected' => ''])

<select {!! $attributes->merge([
    'class' =>
        'pr-10 py-2 rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50',
]) !!}>
    @foreach ($items as $item)
        @if ($item['value'] == $selected)
            @php
                $optionSelected = 'selected';
            @endphp
        @else
            @php
                $optionSelected = '';
            @endphp
        @endif
        <option value="{{ $item['value'] }}" {{ $optionSelected }} @selected(old($attributes->get('name')) == $item['value'])>{{ $item['label'] }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>


// usage

@php

$itemsBlock = [
     [
       'label' => 'Disabilitato',
        'value' => 0,
      ],
      [
        'label' => 'Abilitato',
         'value' => 1,
      ],
 ];

@endphp

<x-select-input :items="$itemsBlock" />
```

This code show correctly a select box.

This select is inside e x-for loop made with AlpineJS, where fields is an array of datata about these select, for example:

fields

```
<div x-data="{fields: [{status: 1}, {status: 0}]}">
   <template x-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
      <x-select-input :items="$itemsBlock" />
   </template>
</div>
```

How to pass `field.status` in my loop to my component `x-select-input` as "selected" props for provide e default selected options?

I have tried

```
<x-select-input class="mt-1" :items="$itemsBlock" ::selected="`${field.status}`" />
```

but doesn't works, any ideas?

Thx all for support!